# Git username incorrect in git bash

Tags: git, git-bash

My office's active directory team recently changed all our AD logons from a username (ex: myname) to an id# (ex: 12345).  Our git box users are not tied to AD, but they mimic the old username method, thus, they are still set up as "myname" rather than "12345".  Now when I connect to Git Bash, it thinks I am "12345@mydomain" instead of "myname@mydomain"

Recap: 
I now log on to my PC as 12345  (I used to as "myname")
Git Bash defaults me to 12345, but that GIT username does not exist, only "myname" exists

Seems git changed my default username when my AD username changed. I have tried modifying git config user.name, but that doesn't seem to work.

Aside from changing my GIT username on our local server, anyone know how I can get this PC to connect to the repo, by way of bash, using my old username?

Comment: If you add your solution as an answer below and mark it as the correct answer, users visiting this page with similar problems will have an easier time solving their problem.

Comment: Thanks - I just figured out how to submit as an answer, I'll mark the checkbox when it lets me (it says I can mark the correct answer in 2 days). Thanks for the info - new to this site. Deleting original "answer" that I posted as a comment.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question was much better than the average new user :)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out -- Went into the tortoise settings for each repo, and under Git: Remote, I highlighted the origin remote. In the URL box, rather than "servername", I now have "myname@servername". This did the trick.